# Large Scenario Outline tables without having to explicitly mention all parameters in the step definitons

Tags: python, gherkin, python-behave

In Python's [behave](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library, I can write a feature file with a parametrised Scenario Outline like so (adapted from [this tutorial](https://jenisys.github.io/behave.example/tutorials/tutorial04.html)):

```
# feature file
Feature: Scenario Outline Example

  Scenario Outline: Use Blender with <thing>
    Given I put "<thing>" in a blender
    When I switch the blender on
    Then it should transform into "<other thing>"

    Examples: Amphibians
        | thing         | other thing |
        | Red Tree Frog | mush        |
        | apples        | apple juice |
```

The according step definitions would look like this:

```
# steps file
from behave   import given, when, then
from hamcrest import assert_that, equal_to
from blender  import Blender

@given('I put "{thing}" in a blender')
def step_given_put_thing_into_blender(context, thing):
    context.blender = Blender()
    context.blender.add(thing)

@when('I switch the blender on')
def step_when_switch_blender_on(context):
    context.blender.switch_on()

@then('it should transform into "{other_thing}"')
def step_then_should_transform_into(context, other_thing):
    assert_that(context.blender.result, equal_to(other_thing))
```

As one can see, the way to pass the parameters from the feature file into the step functions is

- by explicitly mentioning them in the feature file enclosed in angle brackets
- then include the same words enclosed in curly brackets (why not angle brackets again?!) in the decorator of the step function
- and finally insert these words as function arguments of the step function.

However, given a larger example table with a lot of columns, this quickly gets annoying to write and read:

```
# feature file
Feature: Large Table Example

  Scenario Outline: Use Blender with a lot of things
    Given I put "<first_thing>", "<second_thing>", "<third_thing>", "<fourth_thing>", "<fifth_thing>", "<sixth_thing>", "<seventh_thing>" in a blender
    When I switch the blender on
    Then it should transform into "<other thing>"

    Examples: Things
        | first thing | second thing | third thing | fourth thing | fifth thing | sixth thing | seventh thing |
        | a     | b             | c  | d           | e            | f           | g           | h             |
        | i     | j             | k  | l           | m            | n           | o           | p             |

# steps file    
@given('I put "{first_thing}", "{second_thing}", "{third_thing}", "{fourth_thing}", "{fifth_thing}", "{sixth_thing}", "{seventh_thing}",  in a blender')
def step_given_put_thing_into_blender(context, first_thing, second_thing, third_thing, fourth_thing, fifth_thing, sixth_thing, seventh_thing):
    context.blender = Blender()
    context.blender.add(thing)
...
```

I think the point is clear. Is there any possibility to transfer the examples from a large table into the step definition without having to mention all of them explicitly? Are they, for instance, saved somewhere in the context variable even without mentioning them in the text (could not find them there yet)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from considering if one really needs to work with large scenario outline tables (see the other answer), it is indeed possible to access the current table row without explicitly mentioning all parameters in the given/when/then step via `context.active_outline` [(which is a bit hidden in the appendix of the documentation)](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/context_attributes.html).

`context.active_outline` returns a [behave.model.row](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#behave.model.Row) object which can be accessed in the following ways:

- `context.active_outline.headings` returns a list of the table headers, no matter what the currently iterated row is (*first_thing*, *second_thing* etc. in the example from the question )
- `context.active_outline.cells` returns a list of the cell values for the currently iterated row (*a*, *b*, *c* etc. in the example from the question)
- index-based access like `context.active_outline[0]` returns the cell value from the first column (no matter the heading) etc.
- named-based access like `context.active_outline['first_thing']` returns the cell value for the column with the *first_thing* header, no matter its index

As `context.active_outline.headings` and `context.active_outline.cells` return lists, one can also do useful stuff like `for heading, cell in zip(context.active_outline.headings, context.active_outline.cells)` to iterate over the heading-value pairs etc.

Answer (score 0):

The point is clear.

Ask yourself why you *really* need all those variables?

Are you trying to do too much in one scenario outline? Is it possible to split your problem in two?

How would a scenario look like if you just implemented one of them, i.e. skipped the outline? Would it be large and cumbersome?

Unfortunately, I don’t think your problem is that there are many parameter to mention. Your problem is that you are trying to use too many parameters. From where I sit, it looks like you are trying to do too much. Sorry.

Comment: Could not agree more. To translate it to the example, your examples table should not contain all the imaginable ingredients and outcomes but only the representative ones, like this: dried fruit + juicy fruit results in thick juice to drink, but tree bark + motor oil will only give something unconsumable.

Comment: Fair enough. When using the intended way leaves you with an unreadable mess, it's always worth considering whether you should rather change your approach instead of hacking it right.